# How to properly add .a file to Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

i am having trouble with properly adding a library (.a) file into my project. The library have a include folder. Even if I drag paste whole Xcode proj file into my own project, only one header file gets included. Can anyone please tell me step by step procedure how to add a .a file and include all headers from "include" folder of lib to me. Any linking or setting required in my project? please mention that too.